# Logstash pipeline output does not create requested index

Tags: logstash

My output plugin is configured as follows:

```
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:443"]
    ssl => true
    cacert => 'cacert.crt'
    user => "logstash_internal"
    password => "x-pack-test-password"
    index => "logstash-ddo-%{+xxxx.ww}"
  }
}
```

When I query elastic with:

```
GET /_cat/indices/logstash-*?v&s=index
```

I get the following:

```
health status index         uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   logstash-ddo- oyMaZ1jeQPCOhI8YDXnbxw   1   1      78687            0     64.8mb         32.2mb
```

I would expected it to be for example:

```
logstash-ddo-2020-44
```

I have checked and re-checked the pipeline configuration file and I am out of ideas. Do you guys see anything?

Logstash does not report any errors. I'm on version 7.9.2 (dockerized)

Comment: Can you share the rest of your pipeline and a sample of your document before logstash and after? Are you for any reason removing the `@timestamp` field?

Comment: @leandrojmp, you're spot on, I did not remove timestamp but renamed it to ingestion_timestamp as the real timestamp, I want to use for timeline in kibana is part of the log message itself. Post you suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks a lot . Index is now created as expected. Is there a way to base xxxx.ww on a different field?

Comment: I don't think so, logstash uses the `@timestamp` field, so you need to keep it, but you can create a new field with the name `ingestion_timestamp` with the same value using the `mutate` filter.

Comment: That's what I'll do. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an index based on the event's date logstash uses the date from the `@timestamp` field.

Since your index name is not getting the year and the week number, you are either removing or renaming the `@timestamp` field.

You need to keep the `@timestamp` field in your document, if you want to change its name, you can create a new field from it, but logstash needs the `@timestamp` field to create time based index.